# Write an https app in Node and use it on an Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, https, azure-web-app-service

I have written a node.js application which I have been hosting on standard Linux server. It works fine, but I want to move it to Azure. I am not sure how to change the following lines:

```
var options = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_KEY_PATH),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_PATH)
};

if (process.env.CERT_BUNDLE) {
  options['ca'] = [
    fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_BUNDLE_ONE),
    fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_BUNDLE_TWO),
    fs.readFileSync(process.env.CERT_BUNDLE_THREE)
  ]
}

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

I have read [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl) which tells me that instead of my certificated being read from a file the file system that I upload them in the portal.

Then in my node app do I just write `var server = http.createServer(...)` ?
And have Azure take care of the https part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read this guide which tells me that instead of my certificated
>   being read from a file the file system that I upload them in the
>   portal.
>
> Then in my node app do I just write var server =
>   http.createServer(...) ? And have Azure take care of the https part?

This is all correct. SSL termination is a feature of App Service. Your code should only host on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your API services in a cloud environment, you generally should let the platform take care of the SSL decryption instead of your application and not use self-signed certificates.

You would need a load balancer (or [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview)) in front of your NodeJs application to offload the https request via SSL offloading.

Refer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal

Comment: This is not correct, App Service performs its own SSL termination. You do not need Application Gateway.

Answer (score -1):

@Sean,

You can follow the belwo article to deploy a node.js application azure app service.

[Deploy NodeJs application in azure app srevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)

Please ensure to set the set the Node runtime as per your project .

P.S.- Link which is posted above , we are using Azure CLI to deploy application.
Hope it helps.

Comment: great, what about https though?